# toggle radio button remotely

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I need to toggle a radio button remotely, i.e. from an anchor in one div I would like to switch a radio button setting in another div.

The radio button to be switched is the following:

```
<input id="listen" name="view" type="radio" value="audio" checked="checked" onclick = "showPage(1)"/>
<input id="watch" name="view" type="radio" value="video" onclick = "showPage(2)"/>  
<input id="pics" name="view" type="radio" value="photo" onclick = "showPage(3)"/>
```

I would guess that something here (in the anchor, in the separate div) could do this easily:

```
 <a target="mainframe" href="media.html" onclick="???????????????????????????">
```

Suggestions?

Comment: `$('#watch').prop('checked',true)`?

Comment: There's three radio buttons there, which one are you "switching"/"toggling"? Do you want to cycle through each of them in turn? Do you also want to run the associated `onclick` events when they're now selected?

Comment: @DOCASAREL If there isn't a jQuery tag on the question it's generally expected that answers use native JS only.

Comment: I don't mind if this is done with javascript or query, whichever is simpler (I am thinking probably that simple javascript would be here).

Comment: Anthony: I don't want to cycle through them, but rather, just to be able to specify which one will be selected with an "onClick" argument...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist My bad, Sunday dust on my eyes. ;) `document.getElementById("watch").checked = true;`?

Comment: DOC ASAREL - wouldn't that only work for a div in the same page as the anchor?

Comment: It sure does. You cannot alter anything on another **page** with javascript...Anthony?

Comment: Hmmm I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do another sessionStorage or some such thing just to pass this one simple argument...

Comment: Hmm, complex. You want to do this on page load? Do you use `AJAX` for the whole site? That would give you a *state*. Otherwise just do a `query string`?!? You know `www.example.com/?querystring=pics`, whereby you would then grab that with `location.pathname`... and toggle it.

Comment: DOC: I thought about trying the query string approach, but could not get anything to work... I don't have much experience with doing that. How could I add a cue to toggle a radio into the destination URL?

Comment: You would have to do something like a `<form>` and put the querystring by choosing a button: `<form  action="your_page.php" method="get">`. The radio buttons all have to have the same name like `<input type="radio" name="view" value="pics">` as you have, and then the result is sent like `www.example.com/?view=pics`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form. Can not think of anything else.

Comment: DOC- thanks a million! I'll give it a try.

Comment: In case this is of use to someone else trying to do the same thing as me, I did it with the following, VERY simple code taking a query string from the path:

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
 var querystring=window.location.search.substring(1);
 if (querystring == 'audio') {
 showPage(1);
 $("#listen").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh"); }

 if (querystring == 'video') {
 showPage(2);
 $("#watch").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh"); }

 if (querystring == 'photo') {
 showPage(3);
 $("#pics").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh"); }

 else { $("#listen").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh"); }